# how can I have vertical label on my graph by networkx

Tags: python, networkx

I have a graph, which each label is its weight. I want to show its label vertical. How can I do that?

my code is:

```
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pylab

G = nx.DiGraph()
G.add_node('A',pos=(0,100))
G.add_node('B',pos=(2,50))
G.add_node('C',pos=(-2,50))
G.add_node('D',pos=(0,40))
G.add_node('E',pos=(1,10))
G.add_node('F',pos=(-1,10))
G.add_node('G',pos=(0,-50))
G.add_edges_from([('A', 'B')], weight=1)
G.add_edges_from([('F','G')], weight=1)
G.add_edges_from([('C','F')], weight=2)
G.add_edges_from([('A','D')], weight=3)
G.add_edges_from([('D','F'),('E','G')], weight=4)
G.add_edges_from([('A','C')], weight=5)
G.add_edges_from([('B','E')], weight=6)
G.add_edges_from([('D','G')], weight=8)
G.add_edges_from([('B','D')], weight=9)
edge_labels=dict([((u,v,),d['weight'])
                 for u,v,d in G.edges(data=True)])
pos=nx.get_node_attributes(G,'pos')



nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G,pos,edge_labels=edge_labels, rotation='vertical')
nx.draw(G,pos, node_color='lightgrey',with_labels=True, node_size=1000, rotation='vertical')
pylab.show()
plt.savefig('graph.png')
```

I used `rotation='vertical` but it's not really working.

Comment: did you try `rotation=90`?

Comment: @Joel: Isn't it just 'rotate=False' or did you guys change the syntax?

Comment: (I'm not "you guys" fwiw).  I was just guessing based on experience that when `rotation=X` was being used, `X` is often in degrees.  But I see now that `rotate` rather than `rotation` is the right keyword (and it's a boolean).

Comment: what do you mean by "vertical" labels? If you mean text in the standard orientation, going across the page (parallel to x-axis) then `rotate=False` does it as noted.  But the way I interpreted vertical is text going up the page, parallel to the y-axis.  This is possible but not quite out of the box.  Please clarify and I'll answer if necessary

Comment: Thanks @Bonlenfum It works fine `rotate=False` is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bonlenfum answer was correct:

what do you mean by "vertical" labels? If you mean text in the standard orientation, going across the page (parallel to x-axis) then rotate=False does it as noted. But the way I interpreted vertical is text going up the page, parallel to the y-axis. This is possible but not quite out of the box. Please clarify and I'll answer if necessary